# WebApi 2 returns null result

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a simple WebApi action that should return a complex type in json format. Unfortunately the only thing i get is

```
{"Message":null}
```

The object i'm trying to return is nothing special. It basically applies to this form without any annotations:

```
enum A
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

class B
{
    public bool PropertyA { get; set; }
    public int PropertyB { get; set; }
    public string PropertyC { get; set; }
    public A PropertyEnum { get; set; }
}

class C
{
    public bool PropertyA { get; set; }
    public int PropertyB { get; set; }
    public string PropertyC { get; set; }
    public B PropertyClassB { get; set; }
}
```

I get the correct object from a legacy database abstraction.

Now I return the object like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetInstanceOfC([FromBody]SomeObject arg)
{
    try
    {
        // Legacy stuff that constructed the object
        return Ok(data);
    }
    catch(/* ... */)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

What I get from the Api is this, although the Response object looks correct:

```
{"Message":null}
```

I deactivated the XMLMediaTypeFormatter and the Model Binding Validation.

Comment: Are you sure you are not falling to the `catch` block?

Comment: No, it returns the Ok. I don't know what happens inside Ok. Maybe something is failing in the deserialization of the object?

Comment: Is the parameter data dynamic?

Comment: No, the parameter is a BindingModel.

Comment: Is the object intantiated before getting to OK()?

Comment: Are you using EF or ADO.net ?can you show us code in try block?

Comment: something wrong in OK method of 'return OK(data)'.

Comment: did you debug the method to know if you hit the right action ?